# Using Aquamacs for EDITOR in Subversion

Tags: macos, emacs, svn, aquamacs

Is it possible to use Aquamacs as the editor for Subversion.  For example, if I do

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

and I have the EDITOR variable set to "emacs", it will use GNU emacs for the editor to edit that property.

In my .profile, I've

```
alias emacs="open -a /Applications/Aquamacs.app/"
```

So calling

```
emacs foo.bar
```

opens the file in Aquamacs.

Setting the EDITOR variable to "emacs" fails to use Aquamacs.  Setting the EDITOR to '"open -a /Applications/Aquamacs.app/"' DOES open the file in Aquamacs, but since open is not a blocking command (I'm guessing), Subversion continues immediately in the Terminal as if nothing was entered.  In other words, it doesn't wait for the user's edits.

I can't find out if open can be called so that it blocks, or if there's another command in OSX Terminal.  Obviously, I don't know if blocking would even work, since what exactly would it block on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set your EDITOR to `emacsclient` instead of emacs. This is a client interface to emacs internal server.

Configuration (one time):

- set `$EDITOR` to emacsclient: `export EDITOR=emacsclient`
- put `(server-start)` in your `.emacs` startup file

When you run your `svn commit`, `crontab` or other command which uses `$EDITOR`, the file will open in emacs. When you're done editing, hit `C-x #` to return control to `svn`, `crontab`, etc.

Take a look at this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116560/open-an-emacs-buffer-when-a-command-tries-to-open-an-editor-in-shell-mode) and emacs documentation on [emacs server and invoking emacsclient](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html).

---

**Update:** I use a standard emacs build, not Aquamacs, so I googled to see if there were any special tricks required for Aquamacs and emacsclient. On the emacs wiki [Aquamacs FAQ](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AquamacsFAQ#toc23), I found this snippet:

> In order to use the “aquamacs” and
>   “emacsclient” command-line tools, from
>   the Aquamacs menu bar, Tools->Install
>   Command Line Tools. If you are
>   upgrading Aquamacs, you may need to
>   re-install the Command Line Tools.

I imagine that if you don't do this, you'll be using the `emacsclient` that came with OS X and it might not send the right message to Aquamacs.re-install the Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/open -n -W -a /Applications/Aquamacs.app"
```

Comment: In order to use `Aquamacs` with Git I had to apply this, and set `core.editor` to `emacsclient`.